# understanding this cpu utilization script

Tags: printf, header-file, cpu-usage

I need to understand the below Script :

```
HEADER='CPU    pctUser    pctNice  pctSystem  pctIowait    pctIdle'

HEADERIZE="BEGIN {print \"$HEADER\"}"

PRINTF='{printf "%-3s  %9s  %9s  %9s  %9s  %9s\n", cpu, pctUser, pctNice, pctSystem, pctIowait, pctIdle}'

CMD='sar -P ALL 1 1'

FORMAT='{cpu=$3; pctUser=$4; pctNice=$5; pctSystem=$6; pctIowait=$7; pctIdle=$NF}'

FILTER='/Average|Linux|^$|%/ {next} (NR==1) {next}'


$CMD | tee $TEE_DEST | $AWK "$HEADERIZE $FILTER $FORMAT $PRINTF"  header="$HEADER"

echo "Cmd = [$CMD];  | $AWK '$HEADERIZE $FILTER $FORMAT $PRINTF' header=\"$HEADER\"" >> $TEE_DEST
```

This script is actually used to find out cpu utilization (using sar) and print its values.
I am find trouble in understanding the `HEADER`, `HEADERIZE`, `PRINTF`. How are these things working.

Answer (score 0):

The person who wrote the script was simply trying to make it easier to see everything up top that drives the look of the output and the script's functionality. They seem to have failed :) to make it easier for you.

If you read about how awk works (google it or read `man awk`), you'll see it wants a sequence of *pattern* `{` *statements* ... `}`. (This is an over simplification.) The names like `HEADER` and `HEADERIZE` are shell variables whose values are assigned at the top of the script and whose values are used later where they are preceded by "$". See that `$AWK "$HEADERIZE` line? The script is going to run awk (presumably elsewhere the variable AWK is defined as something like `awk` or `/usr/bin/awk` or something like that). The parameters to awk will start with the value of the HEADERIZE variable as defined on the second non-blank line there. So the line will really read (assuming the `AWK` variable is defined to be `awk`):

```
awk "BEGIN {print "$HEADER"}"
```

and so on.

If you want to see how this all works, substitute `echo` for `awk` or redefine the `AWK` variable to be `echo` using something like

```
export AWK=echo
```

and re-run the script. You'll see the command lines as they would have been passed to `awk`.

The reason there are two commands at the bottom appears to be so that the output file, whose name is the value of the variable `TEE_DEST`, will contain two entries as a result of this script's execution. One is from the first command where the output of the execution of a command line from the variable `CMD` will be stored in the file named `$TEE_DEST` and then passed to the `awk` command whose output will be displayed on the *terminal*. Then the second time simply uses `echo` to put the string `Cmd = [$CMD]` through the `awk` script, appending that script's output to the file `$TEE_DEST` as well.

You can find the value of each of a variable named `VARIABLE` easily by using

```
echo $VARIABLE
```

This allows you to run bits of the script by pasting them into your terminal window and examine the contents. This, I have found, is an excellent way to learn scripting.

If you want to *set* a variable's value, you do something like what I suggested above when I told you to overwrite the value of `AWK` with `echo`:

```
export VARIABLE=new value for the variable
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your description is really helpful. need some more help. And you were right awk is defined as below. AWK=awk 
Modified script.
echo $HEADERIZE
$CMD | $AWK "$HEADERIZE $FILTER $FORMAT $PRINTF"  header="$HEADER"
echo $HEADERIZE

echo "Cmd = [$CMD];  | $AWK '$HEADERIZE $FILTER $FORMAT $PRINTF' header=\"$HEADER\""

Comment: Modified Script
HEADER='CPU    pctUser    pctNice  pctSystem  pctIowait    pctIdle'
HEADERIZE="BEGIN {print \"$HEADER\"}"
PRINTF='{printf "%-3s  %9s  %9s  %9s  %9s  %9s\n", cpu, pctUser, pctNice, pctSystem, pctIowait, pctIdle}'

CMD='sar -P ALL 1 1'
FORMAT='{cpu=$3; pctUser=$4; pctNice=$5; pctSystem=$6; pctIowait=$7; pctIdle=$NF}'
FILTER='/Average|Linux|^$|%/ {next} (NR==1) {next}'
echo $PRINTF "Printf function"
$CMD | echo "$HEADERIZE $FILTER $FORMAT $PRINTF"  header="$HEADER"
echo $HEADERIZE "after awk"
echo "Cmd = [$CMD];"  |  awk '$HEADERIZE $FILTER $FORMAT $PRINTF' header=\"$HEADER\"

Comment: But this script is not printing the output of the sar command.

Comment: Hey Metalwheaties,
Kindly advise :)

Comment: Could you edit that so it's readable please? I have only a mobile phone at the moment and it is completely incomprehensible because you didn't put it in as indented code. Thanks.

Comment: OK I think I have correctly decrypted the mishmash the web site made of the script. *Please* use indenting by four spaces for your script in future. Otherwise (as you can see above) it's impossible to read it.